# Discord commands not registering

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and i tried making a discord bot, i got the bot on the server but i cant register the commands. This is the error I'm getting:`DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body application_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "undefined" is not snowflake. guild_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "undefined" is not snowflake. at SequentialHandler.runRequest (c:\Users\Waku\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:708:15)  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (c:\Users\Waku\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:511:14) { rawError: { code: 50035, errors: { application_id: [Object], guild_id: [Object] }, message: 'Invalid Form Body' }, code: 50035, status: 400, method: 'put', url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/undefined/guilds/undefined/commands', requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }`

This is the code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('marco').setDescription('Replies with polo!'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Replies with server info!'),
    
]
    .map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

> Blockquote